# Was the painting a genuine La Tour?

Tags: props, le-divorce

In the Merchant Ivory picture, [*Le Divorce*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306734/) (2003), there is a painting supposedly painted by the French painter, Georges de La Tour, which plays a role in the plot. Was it a genuine painting by this painter?

Comment: I believe I just saw this painting on the wall of the Gold and Silver Pawn shop in an episode of Pawn Stars. Thanks to Cristian for the details.

Comment: @coleopterist: Do either of these answers satisfy you? If not, what sort of information would you like to see?

Answer (score 2):

The “St. Ursula” painting in the movie Le Divorce was painted by the French painter Jean-Paul Letellier specifically for the movie.  No idea on what happened to it.

Comment: It will be better if you can post some reference material to support your answer.

Comment: The information on the painting is listed in the credits at the end of the movie.

Comment: consdier adding this info also in answer to make it more clear +1

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

Georges de La Tour (1593 - 1652) had many beautiful paintings, but this was not one of them. It was invented simply to add authenticity to the story.

If you're interested though, and on a completely different note to your question, Georges de La Tour drew a lot of inspiration from the great Italian artist Caravaggio (1571 - 1610), who *did* have a painting of Saint Ursula, titled "The Martydom of Saint Ursula".

[image: The Martydom of Saint Ursula]

As to your original question though, the answer is a resounding no unfortunately.